# Magento limit admin products

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I'm currently in the process of messing about with Magento, and I'm just wondering if anyone knows where I can modify the collection that is used for `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController` (app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php)? Which method am I rewriting/creating to change the products to show?

EDIT1: I'd rather have a way of using observers, I.e. which event do I need to apply my code to?

EDIT2: best to add here what I'm trying to achieve; I've added an extra attribute to products which holds which admin added that specific product. Now In the admin panel, when a user views the list of products, they only see the products where the that attribute is their admin id.

EDIT3: I just stumbled upon `catalog_product_load_after` event observer, and I'm not sure if this is the right one, but this is what I have:

confix.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_load_after> <!-- Name of Event -->
                <observers>
                    <load_after> <!-- Any Unique Identifier -->
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Drench_Admindetails_Model_Observer</class> <!-- Over Model Class -->
                        <method>loadAfter</method> <!-- name of function -->
                    </load_after>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_load_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

and Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Drench_Admindetails_Model_Observer{
    public function loadAfter(){
        fb('testasd'); // this just a firephp call
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen to `catalog_product_collection_load_before` or `catalog_product_collection_load_after`.

To find the event you're interested in, use Alan Storm's technique: edit app/Mage.php dispatchEvent() method, adding this line at the beginning:

```
Mage::log('Event: ' . $name, null, 'events.log');
```

This will write all events in an /var/log/events.log file.
I'd put a link to Alan's original post, but I can't find it right now: if anyone find it I'll update my answer.

Comment: Great mate! That worked! Turned out to be the event `catalog_product_collection_load_after`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The quickest method is to copy this file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php
```

into your local scope and add new filter to _prepareCollection() function.

However this may not be upgrade-friendly. For an upgrade-firendly solution I suggest to create a new Magento module and append filter to _prepareCollection() function there.

Comment: Thanks for that, however, the events solution is better. If that doesn't work, I will look into this method!